# In Ember.js, how can I force a route to be in the loading substate?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Is it possible to reenter the loading state manually?

Right now I have a template that matches the loading rule mentioned at their [webpage](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/):

> Ember will find a loading route at the above location if
>
> [...]
>
> a properly-named loading template has been found, e.g.
>
> bar/loading
>   foo/loading
>   loading

When transitioning to the page, it uses this template, which is great.  However, I would like to enter that same loading state while my web request busy.  Currently, I am reimplementing that template in the page and toggling it, which duplicates code.  I would rather tell ember when I am in loading state or not manually.

**Edit:** In response to comment, the web requests both set and push data to the model (search button and "infinite scroll" pagination)

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What is your web request?  Is it updating part of the model?  All of the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `transitionToRoute()` to transition into (and out of) a loading route while your request is in progress.